# One white space only

Tags: c#, regex

I need one white space only in my regular expressen.

How should I create the code that validate if one white space is availabe in the string value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean but I'm guessing you want to check for *exactly* one whitespace, but any number of non-whitespace characters:

```
@"^\S*\s\S*$"
```

Example code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\S*\s\S*$");
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("Hello, world!"));
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("This contains three spaces."));
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("Two\nlines."));
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
```

---

**Other variations**

To check if the string contains exactly one whitespace *only* (no other characters):

```
@"^\s$"
```

To check if the string contains *at least one* whitespace:

```
@"\s"
```

Comment: For the second case, one whitespace only, `str != null && str.Length == 1 && Char.IsWhiteSpace(str[1])` is likely to be more efficient than the regex.

Comment: I think you mean `char.IsWhiteSpace(str[0])`?

Comment: Drat. Yes. Why aren't comments editable after 5 minutes?